# amdgpu can't overclock

Tags: amdgpu

I have so far been unable to find much pertaining to overclocking and overvolting on linux with amdgpu. I did find some informtion and had overclocks about a year ago but have lost the scripts. More recently however I have only seen mostly non-functional tools and going by the documentation found here: https://dri.freedesktop.org/docs/drm/gpu/amdgpu.html the interfaces dont seem to work the same and I was unable to see the date for the documentation and suspect it is out of date for the current drivers I am using (20.45). But utilising "echo 's 2 2020 1200' > pp_od_clk_voltage" returns "Invalid Argument". I was wondering if someone had upto date information regarding the amdgpu library and the powerplay features.

While I have found a solution to the previous problem I seem to have created a new problem. For anyone with the issue of being unable to overclock I would recommend checking out CoreCtrl. But with the new issue it seems irregardless of my ppfeaturemask and clocks set when ever I turn of the display the amdgpu dkms fails with a dmesg error "flip_done time out". I am seeing if anyone is aware of this issue.

A large portion of the last issue seems to have been related to kernel 5.11 and the drivers present there, but there is an ongoing thread on Reddit at this address: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/liwsik/amdgpu_drivers_crash/

Comment: I also got the `Invalid argument` message. Seems that the settings in `pp_od_clk_voltage` are already at their max in my case (see `OD_RANGE`).

This is my issue: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/overclocking-amd-radeon-550-2gb-not-possible/129501

Answer (score 0):

I found the [archlinux AMDGPU page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU) quite useful for this though a little dated. They have some links to various tools the most useful of which I found to be https://github.com/sibradzic/amdgpu-clocks, which is a handy script for doing what you want along with having some useful pointers in the readme.

Comment: The problem with archlinux's page I found is that I am unable to utilise the commands used (ie. "echo 's 2 2000 1150' > pp_od_oc_voltage") as I always get permission denied, however I have found the only tool that works at this point as stated in the edit thanks to some reddit users.

Comment: You probably need to use `sudo tee` rather than normal shell redirection. What's the full command sequence you're entering?

Comment: "sudo su; cd /she/class/DRM/card0/device; echo 's 2 2000 1150'" is the command set, each are run separately and depending on weather "sudo echo" is used from user level or I enter a root terminal first I either get "permission denied" or "invalid input"

Comment: @hwh57 Would you mind adding the commands to overclock directly to your answer? It's then easier to comment and edit for correct answer.